Handle refresh token with Redux-observable
I am working on a client app with React, Redux, and Redux-Observable, and I want to make a refresh request every time I receive an AccessDenied exception after the initial request.
The problem is that I have no idea how to do it... I have spent a huge amount of time on it. The only thing I have found is this old guide, which is not working (or I did something wrong).
So if you have any suggestions, please help. I am not asking for ready solution. Maybe someone can point at direction I need to go.
For now my code looks like this:
Epics
export const getDataEpic: Epic<LogoutAction> = (action$, _, { api }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(GET_DATA),
    exhaustMap(() => api.Request(getDataRequest).pipe(
      map((data) => {
        ...handle data
      }),
    )),
  );

export const refreshEpic: Epic<RefreshAction> = (action$, _, { api }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(REFRESH),
    exhaustMap(() => api.Request<RefreshResponse>(refreshRequest).pipe(
      mergeMap(({ data }) => {
        const { success, user, accessToken } = data.auth.refresh;

        const actions: Action[] = [success ? refreshSuccess() : refreshFailure()];
        if (!success)
          return from(actions);

        actions.push(setUser(user));

        api.SetAccessToken(accessToken);

        return from(actions);
      }),
    )),
  );

Global epic ErrorHandler

export const RootEpic: Epic = (action$, store$, dependencies: EpicDependencies) =>
  combineEpics<any, any, any, any>(
    getDataEpic,
    refreshEpic,
    ...
  )(action$, store$, dependencies).pipe(
    catchError((error, source$) => {
      const api = dependencies.api;

      if (api.IsAccessDeniedError(error)) {
        return source$.pipe(
          ofType(REFRESH_SUCCESS),
          takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType(REFRESH_FAILURE))),
          take(1),
          mergeMap(() => {
            return source$;
          }),
          mergeWith(of(refresh())),
        );
      }

      console.error(error);
      return source$;
    }),
  );

It's current behavior is actually sending refresh after data request if it got accessDenied. But it does not dispatch getData action again.
I have already tried so many ways to solve this, and I started to wonder if it is a good idea at all. Also, I have tried to accomplish this by sending a refresh request before the data request, checking if the token expired, and using Redux middleware.

I did solve that issue recently in one app using an interceptor. The nice thing is that you won't be refreshing the token for nothing if the app stays open for hours as it's done lazily, just when needed. I've also made it so that if 2 requests fire at the same time, while there's a refresh of the token, they won't both trigger a refresh, they'll share a cache that is waiting for the token to be refreshed.
Finally, I'm using grpc instead of HTTP but we've built a small library that really mimics the http interceptor interface so it should be easy for you to re-adapt this for HTTP:
export class AuthenticationGrpcInterceptor implements GrpcInterceptor {
  private readonly authenticationFacade = inject(AuthenticationFacade);
  private readonly logger = inject(Logger).source('AuthGrpcInterceptor');
  private readonly oAuthService = inject(OAuthService);
  private readonly invalidatedTokenResponses = new Set<
    AccessTokenResponse['access_token']
  >();
  private readonly datesService = inject(DatesService);

  public intercept(
    requestData: GrpcRequestData,
    next: GrpcHandler
  ): Observable<unknown> {
    if (requestData.method.service.serviceName !== SomeEndpoint.serviceName) {
      return next.handle(requestData);
    }

    this.logger.debug(
      `Intercepted a gRPC request to "${requestData.method.service.serviceName}/${requestData.method.methodName}" on which bearer token is added`
    );

    return this.authenticationFacade.accessTokenResponseResolved$.pipe(
      switchMap((accessTokenResponseResolved) => {
        const accessToken =
          accessTokenResponseResolved?.accessTokenResponse?.access_token;

        if (!accessToken || this.invalidatedTokenResponses.has(accessToken)) {
          // give it some time to refresh the token but let's not accumulate requests
          // indefinitely it could have unwanted effects if a token happens to resolve way later
          return timer(10_000).pipe(
            switchMap(() =>
              throwError(
                () =>
                  new Error(
                    `Couldn't refresh the access token in a reasonable time`
                  )
              )
            )
          );
        }

        return of({
          accessToken: accessToken,
          accessTokenExp:
            accessTokenResponseResolved.parsedAccessToken.exp ?? null,
          refreshToken:
            accessTokenResponseResolved.accessTokenResponse.refresh_token ??
            null,
        });
      }),
      // we've got a non null token, we shouldn't trigger
      // other requests if the token changes after this point
      take(1),
      mergeMap((accessTokenResponseResolved) => {
        const refresh = (refreshToken: string | null) => {
          if (!refreshToken) {
            throw new Error('No refresh token provided');
          }

          this.invalidatedTokenResponses.add(
            accessTokenResponseResolved.accessToken
          );

          return this.oAuthService.refreshToken(refreshToken).pipe(
            tap((newAccessTokenResponse) => {
              this.logger.debug(`Token refreshed successfully`);
              this.authenticationFacade.setAccessTokenResponse(
                newAccessTokenResponse
              );
              this.invalidatedTokenResponses.delete(
                accessTokenResponseResolved.accessToken
              );
              throw new TokenExpired();
            })
          );
        };

        const currentTimeSeconds = Math.floor(
          this.datesService.getNow() / 1000
        );
        const accessTokenExpirySeconds =
          accessTokenResponseResolved.accessTokenExp ?? Infinity;

        const remainingTimeForAccessTokenSeconds =
          accessTokenExpirySeconds - currentTimeSeconds;

        if (remainingTimeForAccessTokenSeconds < 5) {
          this.logger.debug(
            `Token expiring soon or already expired (${remainingTimeForAccessTokenSeconds}), refreshing`
          );

          return refresh(accessTokenResponseResolved.refreshToken);
        }

        requestData.metadata.set(
          'Authorization',
          `Bearer ${accessTokenResponseResolved.accessToken}`
        );

        return next.handle(requestData).pipe(
          catchError((e: { code: GrpcStatus; message: string }) => {
            if (e.code !== GrpcStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED) {
              throw e;
            }

            this.logger.debug(`Invalid token, refreshing`);

            // we've passed a token but unauthenticated came back so
            // at this stage it means we should try to refresh the token
            return refresh(accessTokenResponseResolved.refreshToken);
          })
        );
      }),
      retry({
        delay: (error: unknown, retryCount: number) => {
          if (retryCount > 3) {
            throw new Error(
              `Number of attempts to refresh the token reached the maximum allowed`
            );
          }

          if (error instanceof TokenExpired) {
            this.logger.debug(
              `Retrying request now that the token has been refreshed`
            );
            return of(true);
          }

          return throwError(() => error);
        },
      })
    );
  }
}

class TokenExpired extends Error {}


I really appreciate your help. However, it's not a direct answer, but you managed to give me an idea.
So for now, I just created an interceptor with a pre-request for refreshing the token if it's expired. I have already managed to create one before, but I wanted it to be implemented as an Epic. The Refresh Epic still exists to be executed once during the initial loading of the app.
So it's a decision, and it works. Thank you again. I will leave this question unanswered in case someone suggests another solution.
